# Passing an action type as a parameter c#

Tags: c#

Is there any way to combine the following two methods into one new method by passing the ActionType as a parameter? I would like to call the new single method into two other different methods (Withdraw and Deposit).

```
class Account
{

    enum ActionType
    {
        Withdraw,
        Deposit,
    }

    private void WriteDeposit()
    {
        StreamWriter outputFile;
        outputFile = File.AppendText("account.log");

        outputFile.WriteLine("{0},{1}", DateTime.Now, ActionType.Deposit);
        outputFile.Close();
    }

    private void WriteWithdraw()
    {
        StreamWriter outputFile;
        outputFile = File.AppendText("account.log");

        outputFile.WriteLine("{0},{1}", DateTime.Now, ActionType.Withdraw);
        outputFile.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Yes, have you actually tried and if so what issues did you have?

Comment: @juharr I have tried. But I am unsure how to pass an action as a parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your question the following should work.

```
class Account
{

    enum ActionType
    {
        Withdraw,
        Deposit,
    }

    public void Withdraw()
    {
        WriteAction(ActionType.Withdraw);
    }

    private void WriteAction(ActionType action)
    {
        StreamWriter outputFile;
        outputFile = File.AppendText("account.log");

        outputFile.WriteLine("{0},{1}", DateTime.Now, action);
        outputFile.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: @Hwarden12 I have added a public method that shows how to call the method.

Comment: That makes it so much easier. Thank you very much.